# Convert Product price according to currency in php

Tags: php

I have a website in opencart. Now I want to create it in normal PHP site. So I want to change product price according to currency Like INR to USD OR USD to ERO etc.
While the user changes the currency type, all product price will change in the website. anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: We're not here to write your code. Please come back when you have a concrete coding question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Implement a currency exchange rate table in your DB mapping every currency to the local or default one in your site.This table should also hold the currency code and symbol.
2. You shold use integer combined with the smallest currency sub-unit like penny or cent and don't use double or float for the currency.
3. Use $_SESSION["currency"] to maintain chosen currency across different pages.
4. Consider linking your exchange rate table to a reliable online service to update it dynamically instead of manually updating it multiple times every day.
5. Consider using one of the available free php monetary libraries instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

One way to store the prices in USD by default. You can store in simple file on server or in your database. Once user select the desired currency then simply do the multiplication.

Secondly, you can use the pre-developed APIs or you can find something on GitHub.